# Couchbase Data Loss issue when replica is configured

Tags: performance-testing, couchbase, database-performance, gatling

We are facing data loss issue during performance evaluation for Couchbase server using gatling.

I have created one cluster with 2 nodes(Mac machine) and initialised with 1 bucket and 1 replica.

Gatling test scenario: **50000k 400sec (same request from 2 machine) which will insert total of 100,000 records**.

gatling is successfully executing the scenario and inserting 50000k records from each machine.

First gatling response(1 machine):
[image]

Second gatling response(2 machine)
[image]

**both response shows successful data creation with zero failure.**

But when I check total records from Couchbase server web console using query service, it give records less than 100,000.

[image]

We have done multiple iteration of the tests but we are seeing the same data loss issue with replica 1 or more.

Note: **If i create a bucket with no replica configured, then total number of records and data distribution across node seems to be working perfectly fine.**

Any suggestions for to fix the issue is deeply appreciated.

My gatling scala class:

[image]

so we are hitting data service which is exposed on 8080 port.

Comment: A couple questions to try to help: Version of Couchbase?  Does gatling add the records through an sdk?  Does your query use scan consistency?

Comment: @MattIngenthron, I am using Couchbase 6.0, and I am not using Couchbase SDK, rather i have integrated with spring boot and using Couchbase repository's save method. I did not specify any consistency level so it must be using default one.

Answer (score 1):

Asked some clarifying questions, but note that queries in Couchbase are, by default, eventually consistent with respect to any updates.  You can control this with scan consistency, and details on that are [in the docs](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/settings/query-settings.html).  If you run your query through an SDK, it's usually a simple arg to the query.

My guess is that it's not data loss, but just that the index update is still occurring.

I don't know gatling in any detail, but in your case are you using HTTP against query?  You'll get the best performance through the KV service, directly accessed through one of the SDKs.

Comment: Matt, we have done multiple iteration of the test with number of scenarios but each time we faced data loss issue, we have waited for couple of hours to check whether data is updated or not but to no avail. Yes, gatling is using HTTP request

Comment: Kindly note that everything is working fine when we create bucket with no replica configured

Comment: Just to be sure, so you're having gatling use HTTP requests to port 8093, with an INSERT statement and any errors would be checked?  I note that there are no failures. Thanks.

Comment: Matt, please check gatling class snapshot which is added above and please note that If i create a bucket with no replica configured, then total number of records and data distribution across node is working perfectly fine.

Comment: I am using Couchbase 6.0, and I am not using Couchbase SDK, rather i have integrated with spring boot and using Couchbase repository's save method. I did not specify any consistency level so it must be using default one.

Comment: Got it.  The Couchbase SDK is used by Spring Data Couchbase under Spring Boot.